# What is the Untracked Application Code in the Stackify Prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stackify

I am using the Stackify for the ASP.NET MVC project. It's showing one of the results as the **Untracked Application Code**

[image: stackify result]

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Untracked Application Code" happens because the profiler for Prefix has a set list of commonly used class paths and methods that it looks for. If it just generically profiled everything it see's it could cause spikes in CPU and Memory usage on the machine Prefix is installed on. Stackify has some [documentation](https://docs.stackify.com/docs/prefix-premium-custom-profiling) that will help you configure these classpaths and methods to show up in Prefix

Comment: the link is broken